# AWS CopyObject - need to set different object owner

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

I'm trying to copy file from account A to account B.
When I call this code, the file is copied, but the `owner` is set as account A.

```
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
import { CopyObjectRequest, CopyObjectOutput } from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';

const params: CopyObjectRequest = {
    Bucket: 'some_destination_bucket',
    CopySource: 'source_bucket_name/file_name',
    Key: 'destination_bucket/file_name',
    ExpectedBucketOwner: <account B id>,
  };

copyObject(copyObjectParams).promise();
```

I tried adding `ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control'` but then I get an error of `AccessDenied` during the call to `copyObject`.

Please advise how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was incorrect configuration on the S3 bucket side. It was configured to ignore ACL and set object owner as the file origin account